# excel formula for SUM() where range is based on another cell?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm doing a sheet with this

```
=SUM(A2:A10)
```

And would like to have the range be dependent on the value in cell `D5`.

How can I do this? I looked into CHOOSE function, but that can only handle an array of 256 values. my actual range is several hundred thousand.

I tried this, but excel complained that this won't work:

```
=SUM(A(Sheet1!D5):A10)
```

To reiterate, in my formula, I want the 2 in `A2` be dependent on the number I enter in cell `D5`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [INDIRECT()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) Function:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A" & Sheet1!D5 & ":A10"))
```

Comment: yup. would choose your answer but silly SO makes me wait 12 minutes, and by then I'll be long gone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting my own answer because similar posts go into VBS, and other really complex things.

I solved this with `INDIRECT`:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A"&D5&":A10"))
```

Easy-peasy!